# Is it possible to tap on a marker (thumbnail) in google Maps api v2 and enlarge "zoom in"

Tags: android, android-image, android-maps-v2

i have a marker which in essence is a thumbnail.  So what i would like to know is is it possible to tap on the thumbnail and display a larger thumbnail, sort of like blowing it up or zooming into the thumbnail?  Sorry for the short question.  I don't have any code for this at the moment, but if someone can help i'll post the code as we go along.

Camera Intent:

```
Intent getCameraImage = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
         getApplicationContext().getDir(
                 getResources().getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);

         fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File((Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +
                 "/" +getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)),new Date().getTime() + ".jpg"));

            getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

         startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, TAKE_PICTURE);

        }
```

onActivityResult

```
try {
                  GetImageThumbnail getImageThumbnail = new GetImageThumbnail();
                  bitmap = getImageThumbnail.getThumbnail(fileUri, this);
              } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                  e1.printStackTrace();
              } catch (IOException e1) {
                  e1.printStackTrace();
              }
              {


              MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions()
             .position(theLastPlaceThatTheUserLongClicked)
             .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
             .fromBitmap(bitmap));
             googleMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
            }
        }
 }
```

showFullImage

```
public void showFullImage(View view) {
String path = (String) view.getTag();

if (path != null) {

    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    Uri imgUri = Uri.parse("file://" + path);
    intent.setDataAndType(imgUri, "image/*");
    startActivity(intent);
   }
 }
}
```

So How can i implement the showFullImage into the `onMarkerClick`

`onMarkerClick`

```
 @Override
        public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
     return false;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

```
myMarker= map
            .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(pos)
                    .title(getResources().getString(R.string.reachUs))
                    .snippet("We are here")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.logo_small)));
```

call setInfoWindowAdapter() method on google map object and set a larger image for smae marker by removing it first

```
map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new InfoWindowAdapter() {

        // Use default InfoWindow frame
        @Override
        public View getInfoWindow(Marker arg0) {
            return null;
        }

        // Defines the contents of the InfoWindow
        @Override
        public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {

        myMarker.remove();
        myMarker= map
            .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(pos)
                    .title(getResources().getString(R.string.reachUs))
                    .snippet("We are here")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                            .fromResource(R.drawable.logo_large)));

            return v;

        }
    });
```

also if you want to make it smaller again use a toggle or flag to set small image again.

Just use remove() on marker and it will work

Comment: Thanks, the problem i have though is the marker is added via camera intent and then returned via `onActivityResult` as a thumbnail with a separate class.  The marker(thumbnail) is then placed on the map at that point tapped.  Now I have this code which i think will work to display the full image of the marker with their respective images.  What i would like to know is how can i implement this into the `onMarkerClick`  I have updated my code.

Answer (score 0):

You should handle the marker click event and get the image

```
 myMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(MarkerClickListener);
```

Then you have to get the image from marker and display in seperate image view. 
To zooming or blowing the image you can use any zooming api for images
[Like Here](https://github.com/marczych/ImageZoomLibrary)